Drying polymers (e.g. FDM 3D printing filaments)
As far as I understand, a polymer absorb some moisture and amount of (maximum) moisture that can be absorbed depends on its type (PLA ~1%, ABS? ~10%). Both simple commercial filament dryers and drying ovens operate with heat, keeping the filaments in a slightly less than glass transition temperature environment to eliminate absorbed moisture (not sure if it is possible to eliminate all without a vacuum). Is the heat only way for drying or would keeping the environment dry (<10%) (at room temperature) also cause for material to lose some moisture?
Not sure if I am saying this in correct words; is the heat provided to overcome activation energy (of evaporation, desorption)? Does the activation energy depend on other factors like the RH% of the environment?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Not sure how to clarify the questions
